# Disable "do you want to allow downloads from" prompt in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, catalina

Since Catalina, Safari has been prompting me

> Do you want to allow downloads from example.com?

Every time I try to download something.

How do I completely disable this prompt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's new to Catalina, I think it's new to Safari 13.

Preferences > Websites > Downloads

From the "When visiting other websites" drop down in the bottom-right, select the "Allow" option.

Picture from Catalina:

[image]

Comment: So now when I see the edit, how can you tolerate the nags that come with the "ask" preference ? I tried it yesterday, got ~20 confirmations in an hour and then turned it to allow.

Comment: I doubt I see the nag more than once a month, so I prefer to know a DL is coming to me because I just asked for it specifically. My regular sites I get files from are already set to allow.